# Running socket.io in Google Container Engine with multiple pods fails

Tags: socket.io, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to run a socket.io app using Google Container Engine. I've setup the ingress service which creates a Google Load Balancer that points to the cluster. If I have one pod in the cluster all works well. As soon as I add more, I get tons of socket.io errors. It looks like the connections end up going to different pods in the cluster and I suspect that is the problem with all the polling and upgrading socket.io is doing.

I setup the load balancer to use sticky sessions based on IP.

Does this only mean that it will have affinity to a particular NODE in the kubernetes cluster and not a POD?

How can I set it up to ensure session affinity to a particular POD in the cluster?

NOTE: I manually set the sessionAffinity on the cloud load balancer.
[image]

Here would be my ingress yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-static-ip
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: my-service
    servicePort: 80
```

## Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  labels:
    app: myApp
spec:
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: http-port
  selector:
    app: myApp
```

Comment: Can you post your service too?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Your session affinity looks ok. Can you also add the representative socket.io errors and logging you might have?

Comment: Even without the socket io errors which are a mix of 400 and `failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 501`

I added an express endpoint that sends the internal ip of the node instance as a header. And if I go to it in my browser I'll see that ip change as though it is being Randomly picked.

Comment: You are close: https://deis.com/blog/2016/socket.io-applications-kubernetes/
What seems to be missing is a setting in the GLB to keep your sessions.Can't help you there, but you can update your question

Comment: I updated my question with a pic showing that I manually set sessionAffinity in the google load balancer.

Comment: Using a `LoadBalancer` type it seemed to work, so not sure if ingress supports this or maybe it's a bug?

Comment: Looks like a bug since ingress usually behaves better with your kind of scenario. I suggest you file a bug in k8s (their github has the links on how to file)

Comment: ever solved this?

Answer (score 2):

First off, you need to set "sessionAffinity" at the `Ingress` resource level, not your load balancer (this is only related to a specific node in the target group):

Here is an example `Ingress` spec:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1  
kind: Ingress  
metadata:  
  name: nginx-test-sticky
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: "sha1"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: $HOST
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: $SERVICE_NAME
          servicePort: $SERVICE_PORT
```

Second, you probably need to tune your `ingress-controller` to allow longer connection times. Everything else, by default, supports websocket proxying.

If you are still having issues please provide outputs for `kubectl describe -oyaml pod/<ingress-controller-pod>` and `kubectl describe -oyaml ing/<your-ingress-name>`

Hope this helps, good luck!